# Get columns from MultiIndex dataframe with named labels

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in this form:

```
first        bar                           foo                    
second       one       two     three       one       two     three
0      -2.008137  0.505892 -0.671299 -1.289395 -1.087887 -0.146657
1      -0.786329 -0.501268 -1.454408  2.627911  0.689416 -0.877968
2      -0.697007  0.929783  0.181715  0.533407  0.117859 -0.557975
3      -1.276656 -0.405381 -0.674329  0.117411  1.536421  0.040912
```

I want to select data with indexes based one level names like this:

```
selected = data.xs(('bar', 'two'), level = ['first','second'], axis=1)
```

This Works. However, I would like to select multiple labels in this way. Something like:

```
selected = data.xs(('bar', ['one','two']), level = ['first','second'], axis=1)
```

in order to get:

```
first        bar                 
second       one       two  
0      -2.008137  0.505892 
1      -0.786329 -0.501268 
2      -0.697007  0.929783
3      -1.276656 -0.405381
```

This however, does not work. How can I elegantly select data in this way? It is important that I can use the level names ('first' and 'second').

Answer (score 2):

You can use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
#KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted     
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[:, idx['bar', ['one','two']]])
first        bar          
second       one       two
0      -2.008137  0.505892
1      -0.786329 -0.501268
2      -0.697007  0.929783
3      -1.276656 -0.405381
```

Another solution:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
print (df.loc[:, ('bar', ['one','two'])])
first        bar          
second       one       two
0      -2.008137  0.505892
1      -0.786329 -0.501268
2      -0.697007  0.929783
3      -1.276656 -0.405381
```

But if need select with level names use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) and then select by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) (select columns, so [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is necessary):

```
mask1 = df.columns.get_level_values('first') == 'bar'
mask2 = df.columns.get_level_values('second').isin(['one','two'])
print (df.loc[:, mask1 & mask2])
first        bar          
second       one       two
0      -2.008137  0.505892
1      -0.786329 -0.501268
2      -0.697007  0.929783
3      -1.276656 -0.405381
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer, but I need to use the level names ('first' and 'second')

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `query` method but requires taking a transpose

```
data.T.query('first in ["bar", "foo"] and second in ["one", "two"]').T
#    ⤷ transpose here                                transpose back ⤴
```

***or*** you can set those variables outside the `query` and reference them

```
first = ['bar', 'foo']
second = ['one', 'two']
data.T.query('first in @first and second in @second').T
#    ⤷ transpose here                 transpose back ⤴
```

[image]

---

Heres a less used alternative to this problem

```
data.filter(regex='one|two')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer, but I need to use the level names ('first' and 'second')